# ClassCastException retriving element on a generic list

Tags: java, generics

I have the following clases:

```
public class PagedResult<T>
{
    private Integer count;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer pageNumber;
    private Integer numPages;

    private List<T> result;
    ...
}

public class AbstractDAO <T>
{

    protected PagedResult<T> getPagedResult( String jpqlBusqueda, String jpqlCuenta, List<Object> parameters, Integer page, Integer pageSize, boolean isNative )
    {
     ...
    }
}

public class RecipeDAO extends AbstractDAO<Recipe>
{

    PagedResult<Recipe> search()
    {
       return getPagedResult( "aaaa", "aaaaa", ...);
    }
...
}
```

When I retrive a list of Recipe objects from BBDD using this, all works well up to the point when I try to access a single object in the result list like this:

```
PagedResult<Recipe> result = RecipeDAO.search(...);
Recipe theRecipe = result.getResult().get(0);
```

In this point I get a ClassCastException claiming that Object cannot be converted to Recipe. I try debugging and stopping the program before getting the object and netbeans debugger shows that the PagedResult object contains a list of Recipe objects. It's some kind of problem with the generics declaration, but i can not pinpoint it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is in the `...` in `getPagedResult`?

Comment: Just some jpa Code to run a query with the parameters in the arraylist

Comment: Check if you are importing the same `Recipe` classes in all contexts.

Comment: Your second line should be "Recipe theRecipe = result.getResult().get(0);"

Comment: @Michael Gantman  i already edited the error. It was a problem trying to put the essential to understand the problem without putting all the code.

Comment: What is the exact signature of `PagedResult.getResult` ? I think it should really help if you put all your code in your question.

Comment: @ΔλЛ there is only one Recipe class in all the classpath

Comment: @C.Champagne It's a plain getter method: public List<T>getResult()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the end it wasn't in the generics construcction but in the jpa part. Aparently when you call em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery) the result it's a list of a generic type that cannot be casted to the Recipe. In order to do that you need to call em.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, resultClass ) where resultClass it's Recipe in my case.

In order to get the resultClass dinamically so all stays generic and reusable we can do:

```
Class<T> resultClass = ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```

As I found in this [excelent post](http://blog.xebia.com/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/).